# Position of AD in a full date (BrE)

Tags: dates, format

I know that *AD* comes before the year mentioned and *BC* after—

> 126 BC, AD 33

If I mentioned the full date UK style for BC, it's easy as well—

> 25 December 126 BC (follows the rule of example 1, looks clean too)

But if I had to mention full date with AD, where will the AD go?

> 25 December AD 33 (follows the rule of example 1, but awkward)

or

> 25 December 33 AD? (doesn't follow the rule of example 1, looks cleaner)

Comment: Just use _(B)CE_ instead—problem solved. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, How is it problem solved? Oxford style guide that I refer to says to *replace* BC with BCE and AD with CE—it doesn't say anything about the other rules changing.

Comment: (B)CE is never put before the number, always after. Oxford presumably just forgot to mention that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. I have idealogical issues with (B)CE though. So, AD/BC for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in Latin, in English the conventional usage is to place  ***[AD - Anno Domini](http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/time/g/AD.htm)*** before the date:  from (ancienthistory.about.com):

> - Although, unlike English, Latin is not a word-order language, ***it is conventional in English writing for A.D. to precede the year (A.D. 2010)*** so that the translation, read in word order, would mean "in the year of our lord 2010". (In Latin, it wouldn't matter whether it were written  A.D.2010 or 2010 A.D.)
> - ***Note*** - The abbreviation a.d. may also stand for "ante diem" meaning the number of days before the kalends, nones, or ides of a Roman month. The date a.d.XIX.Kal.Feb. means 19 days before the kalends of February. Don't count on the a.d. for ante diem to be lower case. Inscriptions in Latin often appear only in capital letters.

From : (www.religioustolerance.org)

> - [Proper English usage has AD precede the date](http://www.religioustolerance.org/ce_info.htm) (as in AD 2006) and has BC follow the date (as in 7 BC). 3 This does not appear to be universally followed. A Google search for "1492 AD" returned about 1,650 hits; "AD 1492" returned 1,060. This format is not generally used with CE. A search for "CE 1492" returned only 75 hits; "1492 CE" returned 874.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. I already know that AD will precede the year. But is there any rule that it can precede the year when mentioning the full date, thereby interjecting itself *within* the full date, instead of how smoothly BC trails a full date. I have clarified my question with an edit.

Comment: @LETBP - I don't see why the "rule" should change if you are mentioning a full date. AD comes after day and month but before the year. The reason it looks awkward is that AD is more often used only with years and "Year of our Lord" is generally used with full dates.

Comment: You comments seem the most satisfactory to me. Since the my question is put 'On Hold' by the mods, I will have to do with your answer. Thanks.